# Keep the first character of a sed regex match

Tags: regex, bash, perl, sed, rename

I'm trying to use the `rename` perl command in Debian to rename files and remove detritus from the end of the filename.

The file names may be like this (varying length/nodes before the series/episode identifier)

```
A.TV.Show.S01E01.HDTV.XVid[stuff].avi
Other.Prog.S07E09.WEB.H264[things].mp4
```

And I want to remove everything after the `SnnEnn` bit and keep the file extension. For example

```
A.TV.Show.S01E01.avi
Other.Prog.S07E09.mp4
```

I don't mind having a command per file extension, although a single command that is extension agnostic would be better.

What I have so far is as follows:

```
rename -nv -- 's/[0-9][.].*?[.]avi$/.avi/' *.avi
```

I'm using `-n` just now so it just shows what the rename would do, without doing it.

The problem is it's losing the number at the end of the series and episode identifier - I need it to keep the first character of the matched text then throw the rest away.

What it gives me currently is files named thus:

```
A.TV.Show.S01E0.avi
Other.Prog.S07E0.mp4
```

Any idea how to do this? Is there a better pattern than I'm using?

Comment: I prefer `s/S\d+E\d+\K.*(?=\.[^.]*)//i` to any solution below

Comment: @Borodin neat - didn't know the \K trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need parentheses to capture parts of the strings:

```
s/([0-9])[.].*?[.]([^.]+)$/$1.$2/
```

or, you can use a look-behind instead of the first capture:

```
s/(?<=[0-9])[.].*?[.]([^.]+)$/.$1/
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. It's capturing the part that you want to keep in parentheses, and then referring to it in the replacement as `$1`.

```
rename -nv -- 's/(^.*?S\d{2}E\d{2})\..*?\.(*)$/$1.$2/' *
```

Comment: Cheers - went with @choroba answer as its file extension agnostic - but tested yours successfully also and worked a treat

Comment: No worries, just re-read your question and was in the midst of updating it for future visitors.

Comment: This will fail when _The Simpsons_ runs into its 100th season.

Comment: @StephenP the horror!

Comment: @StephenP :-) `rename -nv -- 's/(^.*?S\d{2,3}E\d{2})\..*?\.(*)$/$1.$2/' *`